# I would like to split a string into array using regex with data factory dataflow, regexSplit function now working for me

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to convert "57%Acrylic27%Polyester14%Polyamide2%Elastane" string to 57%Acrylic   27%Polyester  14%Polyamide  With adf dataflow

This is the input
57%Acrylic27%Polyester14%Polyamide2%Elastane

This is the regex [0-9]+%[A-Za-z]*

This is the output

57%Acrylic

27%Polyester

14%Polyamide

2%Elastane

How to perform this with Azure Data Factory Dataflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below expression to get desired results.

`split(rtrim(regexReplace(<column_name>,  '[0-9]+%[A-Za-z]*','$0 '),' '),' ')`

Here, i am using your expression only to replace the string matched with the original string plus space character.
And then doing `rtrim` so that extra space in right is removed and doing split on space character.

Output:

[image]